# Iphone autoscale

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I have a portrait app that uses auto scale ( not autolayout or auto-resizing).

To achieve full screen on iPhone 5/6/6+ etc before iPhone, I did :-

- Not put launch images in the asset catalog
- Not use a launch storyboard
- Use a launch images Named:Default-568h@1/2/3.png

Reading the various previous posts on this, its not clear if you can get the app to fill the screen on an iPhone X rather than it being a letterbox ( compatibility mode ) ?

I have read various stackflow posts, saying add another launch screen ( although the name of the file isn't clear , have seen )

- Default-812h@3x.png
- Default-375w-812h@3x.png
- Default-812h@3x~iphone.png
- LaunchImage-1100-2436h@3x.png
- LaunchImage-1100-Portrait-2436h@3x.png

Put adding these, doesn't get the app out of letterbox mode. If I put the images inside the asset catalog,use a launch storyboard or even add entires to the plist. The app does't scale , it only shows its original size in the top left corner and the rest of the screen is not used on the larger displays.

So in summary, can you get out of letterbox mode and use the full screen of the iPhoneX, simply by adding another launch screen file ?, custom I can't get it to work.. ?

Note: Using latest Xcode 9.x and I have also tried changes the settings of the app to be IOS10/IOS11, Full Screen enabled/disabled

Comment: Please do your users a favor and write your app correctly so it takes full advantage of all device sizes.

Comment: At a minimum use a launch image asset and then you can populate it with just the few launch images you wish to support. No need to worry about naming conventions or updating the Info.plist yourself.

Comment: @rmaddy, if I add the launch images to the asset catalogue, auto scale stops working.. so whilst I'm work on refactoring, wanted to know if there was a quick win.

Comment: Even if you only add the 320x568 launch image to the asset?

Comment: @rmaddy, if you just at the 320x568@2x only, it still doesn't fill the iPhone X.. still get the top & bottom black bars ( letterbox )

Comment: Right but does it still scale on other devices? One that works, then add the iPhone X image to the launch image asset.

Comment: @rmaddy, so scales fine on all but iPhone X, but soon as you add the iPhoneX image to the asset catalogue.. scaling stops, and the original size is shown top left, with white space on the right and bottom